# publishing a finish game project xna error

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I have finished my game but when i publish it and send it to my friends they all get the same error message while installing (i don't get any error message thou). The error message is requires that assembly microsoft.Xna.framework.gamerservices version 4.0.0 be installed in global assembly cache (GAC) first.

i did more research on my problem and found out that xna publish prerequisite could not be found for bootstrapping.

Comment: XNA is discontinued, use Mono game instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need **[Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0 Refresh](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27598)** to be installed on your friend's computers. This includes the XNA runtime libraries required to run XNA games.

Comment: but is there a way for an installation setup to install my game and xna at the same time from a single setup file?

Comment: Yes. Read this for more info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464156.aspx
Feel free to accept this answer if you think it answered your question :)

Comment: i read that page already and did the "oneclick", but it still didnt work the error was the same for the users without xna :(.

Comment: Try the other option linked on that page : `Using Another Installation Package Tool`